# Knockoutjs with Requirejs - Mapping module

Tags: html, mvvm, knockout.js, requirejs

I want map to my module with help of Knockoutjs and requrejs.
Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<script data-main="js/index2" src="js/libs/require/require.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="review"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index2.js (my main js)**

```
requirejs.config({
    // Path mappings for the logical module names
    paths: {
        'knockout': 'knockout/knockout-3.3.0',
        'jquery': 'jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min',
        'jqueryui-amd': 'jquery/jqueryui-amd-1.11.4.min',
        'signals': 'js-signals/signals.min',
        'crossroads': 'crossroads/crossroads.min'

    },

    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: ['jQuery', '$']
        },
        'crossroads': {
            deps: ['signals'],
            exports: 'crossroads'
        }
    },


});




require([
     'test'
    'knockout',
    'jquery'
],
         function (test, oj, ko, $) 
         $(document).ready(function () {

            ko.applyBindings(test,
                        document.getElementById('review'));



      }

);
);
```

**test.js** (Module)

```
alert("Test done!!!");
```

Comment: What issue are you having? Which part is not working?

Comment: i think my binding is nt working

Comment: Where is the *test.js* file located relative to *index2.js*? Try changing `require(['test', 'knockout', 'jquery'])` to `require(['.\test', 'knockout', 'jquery'])`

Comment: i have checked path.That is fine

Comment: So, which part is not working? Are your files being downloaded? What outcome are you expecting? Are there any errors in the console?